# Is there a standardised export of jsplumb JSON models?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jsplumb

Is there a way of exporting a JSON file from a project using jsplumb? Can this be achieved using JavaScript or jQuery alone or is PHP required?

Answer (score 0):

By using

```
var t = jsPlumbToolkit.newInstance();

var data = t.exportData();
```

**Ref:**

https://docs.jsplumbtoolkit.com/toolkit/current/articles/loading-and-saving-data#exporting